# Conditional text color formatting in Rails 4.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to do some conditional formatting in my views.

Please find the sample image for the reference.

[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV7pS.png)

I want to display "cash received" in red color.

At first I would like to check for the condition in such a way that if "cash" is present in description then the whole string that is "cash received" must be displayed in red color.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <% balance = 0 %>

  <div class="table-responsive myTable">

    <table class="table listing text-center">
      <tr class="tr-head">
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>Discount</td>
        <td>Paid</td>
        <td>Balance</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

 <% @statements.each do |statement| %>

      <tr class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

        <td class="col-1"><%= statement.date %></td>

        <% color = (statement.description == "TT" || statement.description == "cash") ? "neg" : "pos" %>

        <td class="col-3 <%= color %>"><%= statement.description %></td>

        <td class="col-1"><%= number_with_precision(statement.amount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

        <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(statement.discount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

        <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(statement.paid, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>


        <% balance += statement.amount.to_f - statement.discount.to_f - statement.paid.to_f %>

        <% color = balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg" %>

        <td class="col-1 <%= color %>"><%= number_with_precision(balance.abs, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

      </tr>

      <% end %>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

newly edited index.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <h1>361° YAZD Statement</h1>

  <% balance = 0 %>

  <div class="table-responsive myTable">

    <table class="table listing text-center">
      <tr class="tr-head">
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>Discount</td>
        <td>Paid</td>
        <td>Balance</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>


      <% @statements.each do |statement| %>

      <tr class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

        <td class="col-1"><%= statement.date %></td>


        <td class="col-3"><%= span_with_possibly_red_color statement.description %></td>

        <td class="col-1"><%= number_with_precision(statement.amount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

        <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(statement.discount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

        <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(statement.paid, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>


        <% balance += statement.amount.to_f - statement.discount.to_f - statement.paid.to_f %>

        <% color = balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg" %>

        <td class="col-1 <%= color %>"><%= number_with_precision(balance.abs, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

      </tr>

      <% end %>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

statements_helper.rb

```
require 'active_support/concern'

    module StatementsHelper



        extend ActiveSupport::Concern
        include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper



        def span_with_possibly_red_color(content)
            classes = if content.split.map(&:downcase).include?("cash")
                {class: "red"}
            else
                {}
            end
            content_tag(:span, content, classes)
        end


    end
```

html output for failing items;

for **cash**

```
 <td class="col-3"><span class="red">cash</span></td>
```

for **cash received**

```
<td class="col-3"><span class="red">cash received</span></td>
```

Comment: This would be better off tagged with jQuery as its DOM manipulation. Doing extra work on the server like his isn't an efficient solution for most cases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please guide how would I go for that in a simple way.

Comment: See my solution below and linked jsfiddle to see it in action.

Comment: Thanks, how would I do in my code...

Comment: Well you would put the jQuery I used below into the relevant js file in Rails. For simplicity (although you shouldn't) put it into `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` and change make sure the ID of the table matches. In my case I used `#mytable` but you should use whatever you have set in your `<table>`

Comment: Sir, linked jsfiddle not working

Comment: I disagree on using javascript for this. That would be barely reusable, while implementing this in a helper funcion will enable refactorings, generalizations etc, on the other side having it in javascript code will lead to lost code somewhere on one page, and few (or at least more complex) patterns to apply when generalizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a view helper like

```
require 'set'

RED_WORDS = %w[cash tt].to_set

def span_with_possibly_red_color(content)
    classes = if (RED_WORDS & content.split.map(&:downcase)).present?
        {class: "red"}
    else
        {}
    end
    content_tag(:span, content, classes)
end
```

and use it in your view

```
<%= span_with_possibly_red_color statement.description %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great reply but unfortunately I am not getting the result.

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen any output? I have written it from memory, so it might have errors. You might need to include `ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper` and to extend `ActiveSupport::Concern` to get one helper's method inside of another helper.

Comment: I edited as per your advice, please let me know are both index.html and statement_helpers.rb are correct?

Comment: Can you add the html output of the failing lines? Actually the simplest failing example (something like `<%= span_with_possibly_red_color "this span should be red because it has cash" %>`) and its output would be great.

Comment: also, extend AS:Concern before including other modules, and require at the top of the file.

Comment: Sir, I have extended AS:Concern before other module. I put html outputs for cash and cash received items as above.please check?

Comment: so it works, you just need to add the correct CSS so a `span` with class `red` has the right color. I imagine that your CSS looks for a `td`. But as you can see the class is applied to a `span`, so the CSS could be something like `span.red { background: red; }`.

Comment: Yes, Sir it is working but the description name with "TT" also must be checked for its presence and must appear in red.

Comment: so change the helper, and check for "tt" too (well, you could improve it by using some constant, I'll edit the response to show you)

Answer (score 1):

In terms of achieving this in jQuery as requested by OP in comments:

jquery:

```
$('#mytable td:nth-child(2):contains("cash")').css("color", "red")
```

HTML:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr><td>date</td><td>cash received</td><td>amount</td></tr>
    <tr><td>date</td><td>Blabla</td><td>amount</td></tr>
    <tr><td>date</td><td>Blabla</td><td>amount</td></tr>
    <tr><td>date</td><td>Blabla</td><td>amount</td></tr>
</table>
```

And a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9wzgpjer/1/):
click run to see it working.

Comment: I just fixed the fiddle link there: it should be working now http://jsfiddle.net/9wzgpjer/1/

Comment: Yes,it is working fine but how can I implement the same to my table containing class?

Comment: Like this: `$('.yourTableClassHere td:nth-child(2):contains("cash")').css("color", "red")`